# Computer shuts off playing games

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

I just re-installed Enemy Territory after not playing for a year and can only play for 5 - 10 minutes and computer shuts off as if I unplugged it, no warning or freezing.  Press power button restart computer, no error messages or anything, starts normal and works fine. I installed Urban Terror and tried it same result.
Computer is on pretty much 24/7, someone is usually on it most of the day and at night I have it performing other tasks, never any problems, I install all updates as they arrive.

Release 12.04 (precise) 32-bit,
Kernel Linux 3.2.0-49-generic-pae,
GNOME 3.4.2,
Memory:1.8 GB,
Processor: AMD Athlon(tm) II X2 245 Processor × 2

GeForce 6150SE nForce 430,
NVIDIA Driver Version:295.49

Comment: How much hot is your computer when this is happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computer's crashes could be caused by several possible reasons. I will discuss one possible reason, overheating, in this answer. Overheating is an easy problem to detect. You can continually monitor your computer's hardware temperatures using an application from the Ubuntu Software Center called Psensor.

Install Psensor with `sudo apt install psensor sensors-applet`. Also install lm-sensors to detect your computer's hardware sensors. Then detect your computer's hardware sensors by opening the terminal and running the command:

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

Then you will get asked a lot of questions about what hardware you want the program to detect.  It is generally safe and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions, unless you know what you're doing.

In Ubuntu 16.04 and later Psensor detect your computer's hardware sensors automatically without running `sudo sensors-detect`

Psensors is displayed on the desktop as a little thermometer icon in the notification area in the upper right-hand corner of the desktop. You can right-click the thermometer icon at any time to display the hardware temperatures. As a general guideline, a hardware temperature of 60<sup>o</sup> C is hot. A hardware temperature of 70<sup>o</sup> C and above is too hot, and could cause your system to crash.

Comment: Thank you, I have installed Psensor and run lm-sensor, I now have the thermometer icon in notification area and it is set up to start whenever the the computer starts.

Comment: Different models of CPUs, GPUs, etc. can have different ranges of recommended operating temperatures. You can often find out the recommended temperature ranges for your own hardware by searching on the manufacturer's website.

Comment: I set my screen resolution in game to exact same as my desktop resolution, (read this in a gaming forum) went in and played 3 maps, exited game and K10temp-pci-00c3 was 83C,(I believe this is Ram) Gpu0 which says Nvidea Temperature is 0C I must not have a sensor on video card.  I run Memtest86 on start-up and it passed no errors.  I did notice L1 Cache and L2 Cache were different sizes was not sure if that is normal L2 being almost double of L1. Temperatures seem to stay between 40 to 46 C, I am taking computer apart tonight and give it a good cleaning, that should take temps down some more.

Comment: Temperatures of 40-46 degrees are OK. L2 CPU cache is usually larger and much slower than L1, though still much faster than going out to RAM.

Comment: Cleaned computer, removed fans, blew out heat sinks, took power supply apart cleaned it (power supply was a mess). played ET for 3 hrs tonight, came out of game, Ram was running at a cool 29C and no crashes, Thanks again karel.